# How to append into a dataframe for many files within a loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am trying to extract data from many docs files and append them into a dataframe.

The code I had written works great when it comes to a single file, but I cant seem to append into the dataframe for more files.

```py
import re
import docx2txt
import pandas as pd
import glob

df2=pd.DataFrame()
appennded_data=[]

for file in glob.glob("*.docx"):
    text = docx2txt.process(file)
    a1=text.split()
    d2=a1[37]
    doc2=re.findall("HB0....",text)
    units2=re.findall("00[0-9]...",text) 
    df2['Units']=units2
    df2['Doc']=doc2[0]
    df2['Date']=d2
df2
```

This gives an error 
"Length of values does not match length of index"

Expected output-

From docx1: (Which I get)

```
Units |  Doc    |   Date

001   |  HB00001 | 23/4/12

002   |  HB00001 | 23/4/12

003   |  HB00001 | 23/4/12

004   |  HB00001 | 23/4/12

005   |  HB00001 | 23/4/12
```

From docx2:

```
Units |  Doc    |   Date

010   |  HB00002 | 2/6/16

011   |  HB00002 | 2/6/16
```

Final output:

```
Units |  Doc    |   Date

001   |  HB00001 | 23/4/12

002   |  HB00001 | 23/4/12

003   |  HB00001 | 23/4/12

004   |  HB00001 | 23/4/12

005   |  HB00001 | 23/4/12

010   |  HB00002 | 2/6/16

011   |  HB00002 | 2/6/16
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please share the format of your word doc file ? Is it a table or something else. We will help you out better if we get to know this.

Comment: can you check a1 & doc2 contents to see if the specified index is valid?

Comment: Hi, its just a docx file with text in it. No tables or lists or anything. The text processing works well and I am able to create a dataframe with just one file. I am just unable to append the dataframe for the other doc files.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the lengths of the columns are not the same. The moment the second file is processed, it will be trying to set the columns to values that have a different length to the first file. You cannot assign a column with values that are different to the existing columns.

Since you want the final df to have columns `['Units', 'Doc', 'Date']`, what you can do is to create a blank df and just append the new results to it. Use `ignore_index=True` to just append it below without trying to match row indexes.

```
import re
import docx2txt
import pandas as pd
import glob


final_df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in glob.glob("*.docx"):
    text = docx2txt.process(file)
    a1 = text.split()
    d2 = a1[37]
    doc2 = re.findall("HB0....", text)
    units2 = re.findall("00[0-9]...", text)

    # because columns are different length, create them as separate df and concat them
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    unit_df = pd.DataFrame(units2)
    doc_df = pd.DataFrame(doc2[0])
    date_df = pd.DataFrame(d2)
    # join them by columns. Any blanks will become NaN, but that's because your data has uneven lengths 
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, unit_df, doc_df, date_df], axis=1)

    # at the end of the loop, append it to the final_df
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, df2], ignore_index=True)

print(final_df)
```

Comment: Replaced it at the end after the for loop, but still got the same error.\

Comment: what are the column names of the final dataframe you wish to obtain? do you want it to be [units, doc,date,units, doc,date,units, doc,date, ...] or [units, doc,date] ?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to first build a dict with the contents and create the DataFrame in the end:

```
import re
import docx2txt
import pandas as pd
import glob

columns = ['Units', 'Doc', 'Date']

data = {col: [] for col in columns}

for file in glob.glob("*.docx"):
    text = docx2txt.process(file)
    a1=text.split()
    d2=a1[37]
    doc2=re.findall("HB0....",text)
    units2=re.findall("00[0-9]...",text) 
    data['Units'].extend(units2)
    data['Doc'].extend(doc2[0])
    data['Date'].extend(d2)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: It returns an error ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Comment: In your data, are `units2`, `doc2[0]` and `d2` the same length for all files?

Comment: In that case, `units2` cannot be used as a column in this `DataFrame`, because all columns  need to have the same length. Unless you want to fill the missing values with `NaN`s or some other value - but that depends on your use case

Comment: Ive edited my question to show how I am currently getting the results, and how I am trying to merge them as.

Comment: I believe your RegEx is wrong. `re.findall("00[0-9]...",text)` will not capture `010` or `011`. Try `re.findall("^([0-9]{3})+", text)` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I just used that as an example. The regex I am using is required for my data. Its just the merging or appending the two files that is the problem.

Comment: As mentioned, unless `units2`, `doc2[0]` and `d2` are the same length, you will not be able to fit them into one single `DataFrame`. You could try the following before creating `df2`: `data['Units'].extend([np.nan]*(len(data['Doc'])-len(data['Units'])))`. But this might not be what you want.